# Multiple Tor hidden services

Tags: configuration, onion-services

If your running lets say three hidden services will they all have the same exit realy if so is it possible through torrc config or something to have different exit relays or even circuits?

Comment: Full separation is not possible by directives, it is done via tor logic itself, automatically. Post your torrc here and I will be able to help you further

Answer (score 1):

Each hidden-service will select its own set of introduction points, and hidden services don't use exit-relays at all.